# Switch not working as expected

Tags: switches

I have what I think to be a DPST switch. My problem is when I plug it into my circuit, it seems to be closed regardless of whether I press it or not. I have tested with another of the same type of switch but with the same results, so I think that either my circuit is wrong or I don't understand how to use this switch properly.

The text underneath the switch reads:

ZYCF
181

Attached are photos of the circuit, the switch and its packet.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: next time, use a multimeter or something with resistance/continuity testing and just probe the pins and play around by pushing the button and see if they beep or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your switch is similar to the one in the picture below, it's likely that you just picked the wrong pins. Try to rotate it 90 degrees, or use diagonally opposite pins.

[image: Image source: Sparkfun]

https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/00097.jpg

Comment: Yes, it's diagonally opposite pins which connect upon pressing the button

Comment: Note that it's not DPST, but a simple SPST N.O. momentary switch.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch is most likely SPST with 2 pins common to each contact and you've connected across the common (shorted) pins. Unplug the switch, turn it 90 degrees, plug it back in, and see what happens.